# In Django, how can I get a count of records based on a subquery of a subquery?

Tags: sql, django, django-models

A baseball player plays in a game if he makes one or more appearances in that game. So, to get a count of the number of games a player played in, you need to count the games that have an inning that have an appearance by that player.

Here are my models:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    ...

class Game(models.Model):
    ...

class Inning(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Appearance(models.Model):
    inning = models.ForeignKey(Inning, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The SQL query to achieve what I want is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM games_game
WHERE id IN (SELECT game_id
             FROM innings_inning
             WHERE id IN (SELECT inning_id
                          FROM appearances_appearance
                          WHERE player_id = 1))
```

How could I do this in Django without using Raw SQL?

Note that this is for a `PlayerDetailView`, so I just need it for a single `Player` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform such count with:

```
Game.objects.filter(inning__appearance__player=my_player).distinct().count()
```

Where *`my_player`* is the player where you want to count the `Game`s for.

Comment: Please add a second underscore between appearance and player. Thanks!